# Drools 6.1.0 - Using KIE Workbench How to create and deploy rules, decision tables, and workflows with human interaction?

Tags: jakarta-ee, drools, kie

I have got KIE workbench up and running using [this](http://blog.athico.com/2014/04/deploying-kie-drools-wb-on-tomcat.html) blog and at this point I am trying to find information as in the last line of **[this](https://skills421.wordpress.com/2014/08/09/drools6-1-workbench-on-jboss-as7-1-1/)** blog

How to create and deploy rules, decision tables, and workflows with human interaction?

Answer (score 2):

When I was learning the KIE Workbench, I found a useful series of videos on youtube that helped a lot.

1. [Part 1: Creating a new Project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM9cuL_Mfnk)
2. [Part 2: Adding a Data Model and Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VebltONoB5g)
3. [Part 3: Creating Rules and Diverging Process Flows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8EMUgBqSHQ)

I hope these videos help. I could try describing what needs to be clicked but I think the third video should help. Just a word of warning about something that took me a while to figure out; the rules engine will only work on Data Objects and not Simple process variables such as String or Integer.

Comment: @Mike The rule engine "works" on any Java object inserted as a fact. This most certainly includes String, Integer, Long, all Enum, etc. Although (but that's another side of the coin) writing rules with patterns referencing these classes isn't likely to be useful.